# How I can open my custom post in single page?

Tags: wordpress

I have registered a custom post in my functions.php. Which post come from custom post category in my page but it does not work on single.php. when i click on read more that created with  but don't open as single page.

Comment: Please show us the code you use to register your Custom Post Type.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a different template to display your custom posts. Try copying the contents of single.php to a file named single-{post_type}.php. See the Codex for more details:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Comment: You are correct in that you can create a dedicated tempate `single-{post_type}.php`, but there is no requirement. See the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

Comment: True. If single-{post_type}.php is missing then WordPress will look for single.php and then look for index.php if single.php is missing.

Comment: @david-gard I edited my answer to say "you could try" instead of "you will need to"

Comment: Thanks for replying. i have follow your suggestions but it is not working. if i click my permalink it show 404 ERROR.

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The template `single.php` should be sufficient for Custom Post Types, as shown in the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

This could be a rewrite rule issue. If you are not using the default Permalinks, try switching to them, save, and then go back to your chosen structure for WP to correctly include the rules for your new Post Type.